# Strapi v4 deep sorting with relational table values

Tags: sorting, strapi

I'm trying to deep sort an API request via endpoint but it doesn't seems to work.

This is the structure:

```
article
 - articles [a list of article entity]
   - article_category
```

It just not sorting

```
/api/articles/5?populate[0]=articles.article_category&sort[1]=articles.title:desc

populate: articles.article_category
sort: articles.title:desc
```

It just not sorting

```
/api/articles/5?populate[0]=articles.article_category&sort[0]=articles.title:desc&sort[1]=articles.article_category.title:desc

populate: articles.article_category
sort: articles.title:desc
sort: articles.article_category.title:desc
```

How can I deep sort